# MySQLで浮動小数点数の数字の挿入について

Tags: mysql

MySQLで浮動小数点の数字を挿入しようしているのですが、
「2.6」は「2.6」で入るのですが、「3.0」は「3」としては入ります。
「.0」まで入れることはできないでしょうか。

---

コメントありがとうございます。

・float_value(型：float)に「2.6」を入れた場合は「2.6」がそのまま入ります

```
INSERT INTO `test` (`float_value`, `created_at`, `updated_at`) VALUES (2.6, '2019-04-07 19:08:06', '2019-04-07 19:08:06')

SELECT * FROM test

=> float_value | created_at          | updated_at
　　　　2.6　| 2019-04-07 19:08:06 | 2019-04-07 19:08:06
```

・しかし、「3.0」を入れた場合は「3」が入ってしまいますが、「3.0」を入れることはできないんでしょうか？

```
INSERT INTO `test` (`float_value`, `created_at`, `updated_at`) VALUES (3.0, '2019-04-07 19:08:06', '2019-04-07 19:08:06')

SELECT * FROM test

=> float_value | created_at          | updated_at
　　　　　3　| 2019-04-07 19:08:06 | 2019-04-07 19:08:06
```

Comment: 「浮動小数点の数字を挿入」というのは、何に何を”浮動小数点の数字”として挿入しているのですか？ その部分のコードを質問に追加してください。

Comment: 挿入方法ではなく、取り出し方に問題があるように思われますので、取り出し方を提示してください。

Comment: 数値型のカラムには、数としての値が格納されるので、float型の数として同じ値である「3」と「3.0」は区別されません。どのような理由で`.0`が必要なのですか?

Comment: 表示をさせる時に「3.0」として表示させたかったので、そのように格納できたら楽だと思い、質問させていただきました。素直に、表示させるところで整形します。ありがとうございました。

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`INSERT`時ではないですが、`SELECT`時に`FORMAT`などを利用するのは駄目なのでしょうか？

こういったデータがある場合に、
[image: DataSet]

下記を実行した結果になります。

```
SELECT FORMAT(`float_value`, 1), created_at, updated_at FROM test
```

[image: Results]